# Xampp Vhost not working with different port

Tags: php, ajax, xampp, vhosts

I created a virtual host in xampp. I cannot use port 80 so I'm using port 8080. I then call servername:8080 to get the index.php. It works fine but I cannot do an ajax call, then an error occurs. What is wrong?

vhost

```
 <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
   DocumentRoot "somepath"
   ServerName servername
   <directory "somepath">
      usual stuff here
   </directory> 
 </VirtualHost>
```

Call index.php

```
http://servername:8080
```

Error ajax

```
GET http://servername:8080/contact.html 404 (Not Found) 
jquery-2.1.0.min.js:4l.cors.a.crossDomain.send jquery-2.1.0.min.js:4o.extend.ajax 
jquery- 2.1.0.min.js:4o.(anonymous function) jquery-2.1.0.min.js:4start_loading
 main.js:516click_internal_link main.js:547(anonymous function) 
main.js:670o.event.dispatch jquery-2.1.0.min.js:3r.handle
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:** (open by xampp panel the Apache config and in the end add the following:)

```
Setting Up Your VHOST
    =====================

    The following is a sample VHOST you might want to consider for your project.

    NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

VHOST for Windows
=====================

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/..." 
   ServerName localhost

   # This should be omitted in the production environment
   #SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
   #SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production

   <Directory "C:/xamp/htdocs/...">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**AND this:** in your windows hosts

```
   C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc
    Edit hosts:

    127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Good luck ;)

Comment: whiche config file? do you have a link with explanation?

Comment: Hey my friend... better than it, see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=St49oetWUMI